# Edit default properties in "identify features" tool QGIS 2.18.2

Tags: editing, identify

I have a few rasters and want to see their values. When I use the "identify features" tool, I first get the option of "identify all" (see attached image) and only when I click on that I can see the results, but in "Tree" view (that is the default)

[image]

Is it possible to change it so I won't have to click on "identify all" every time, so that the results will appear automatically? and that the "view" mode will be set to "Table"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the mode in identify layers from 'Layer selection' to 'Top down'. Then it works by default all layers.

[image]